# How to host mp3 files in shared hosting that can also be play online without downloading?

Tags: hosting, mp3, shared

Is there a website that can host mp3 and play them online? I tried mailboxdrive.com but I can't host mp3 today in that website? Is there any alternative or can I host mp3 in my shared hosting that can play online(Without downloading)?

Comment: Soundcloud can play sound and not downloadable(unless you give acces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a website that can host mp3 and play them online?

Sure.  Any can.  It's just a file like anything else.  Throw it in an S3 bucket or something.

> (Without downloading)?

No, that's impossible.  If you can play it, you can download it.